# NotOnOrAfter Condition when using SubjectConfirmation elements in a SAML assertion‏

Tags: saml, pac4j

I have been asked if my SAML implementation (using pac4j) implements NotOnOrAfter Condition when using SubjectConfirmation elements in a SAML assertion

my implementation set setMaximumAuthenticationLifetime() but I am not sure if answers the question

1. Do I have any control on such validations? if yes then how do I config it
2. what is the default behavior

thanks,
Eyal

understand what is the meaning of these validations and how can I control the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

After a succesfull login at the SAML IdP, the SAML response is validated by pac4j.

Yes, the `NotOnOrAfter` condition is checked against the current time with the `acceptedSkew`: https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/5.7.x/pac4j-saml/src/main/java/org/pac4j/saml/sso/impl/SAML2AuthnResponseValidator.java#L486

The issue instant is also checked against the `maximumAuthenticationLifetime`: https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/5.7.x/pac4j-saml/src/main/java/org/pac4j/saml/sso/impl/SAML2AuthnResponseValidator.java#L622